# Php foreach to unordered html list

Tags: php, foreach

I can make foreach ordered list but turn come to unordered im using so strange things . I want to loop my object like below:

[image]

My html code :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-1.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-2.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-3.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-4.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
</div><!--//row-->

<div class="row height-20">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/blog/blog-large-1.jpg">
<div class="large-blog-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post Check it out lorem ipsum!</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--/col-xs-6 col-md-6-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/blog/blog-large-1.jpg">
<div class="large-blog-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post Check it out lorem ipsum!</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--/col-xs-6 col-md-6-->
</div><!--//row-->

<div class="row height-20">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-1.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-2.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-3.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-4.jpg">
<div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--//col-md-3-->
</div><!--//row-->

<div class="row height-20">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/blog/blog-large-1.jpg">
<div class="large-blog-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post Check it out lorem ipsum!</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--/col-xs-6 col-md-6-->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
<a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
<img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/blog/blog-large-1.jpg">
<div class="large-blog-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post Check it out lorem ipsum!</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
</a>
</div><!--/col-xs-6 col-md-6-->
</div><!--//row-->
```

As u see there is a main row (class class row) and o it for each content has container (if its 4column : col-xs-6 col-sm-3 and if 2 columns : col-xs-6 col-sm-6)

How can i make a list like above with my object array ?

what i did :

```
<?php
    $open_div = true;

    foreach($content as $key => $val) { 
        if($key > 0 and $key < 4) { 
           $open_div = false;
        } else {
           $open_div = true;
        }  
?> 

<?php 
    if($open_div == true) { 
        $open_div = false; 
?>   
    <div class="row">
<?php 
    } 
?>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
       <a href="blog-detail.php" class="anim-opacity">
       <img class="img-responsive margin-auto" alt="" src="images/foto-kombin/foto-kombin-1.jpg">
       <div class="blog-image-text"><div class="text">Robin Givhan Returns to The Washington Post</div><div class="user">GÖKHAN ŞAHİNKAYA</div></div>
    </a>
    </div><!--//col-md-3-->

<?php 
     if($open_div == true) { 
?>
    </div><!--//row-->
    <div class="row height-20">&nbsp;</div>
<?php 
    } 
 } // foreach end?>
```

Comment: we don't need only tag of `foreach`, post your code too.

Comment: I would just float it and skip column widths. Please intend your code next time and show what you've tried, this is #§$%!

Comment: i add code on question

Comment: Images were enough for what ?

Comment: So far I understand, You want to be 4 columns, 2 columns and 4 columns layout . right? What  you mean `$open_div` Where its used?